# Jump skill with Boots of Striding and Springing

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, skills

Do these boots effectively provide a +9 to the Jump skill?

+5 competence bonus
+4 untyped bonus from increased land speed (mentioned in the jump skill description)

Comment: Your Jump check is modified by your speed. If your speed is 30 feet then no modifier based on speed applies to the check. If your speed is less than 30 feet, you take a -6 penalty for every 10 feet of speed less than 30 feet. If your speed is greater than 30 feet, you gain a +4 bonus for every 10 feet beyond 30 feet.

Comment: It's not racial sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Close enough: *Yes*

A bonus to a creature's speed (like from the [*boots of striding and springing*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsWI.html#boots-of-striding-and-springing)) grants the creature a bonus to its [Jump](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/skillsAll.html#jump) skill checks: each +10 ft. over 30 ft. grants the creature a +4 bonus on Jump skill checks.

Likewise, a reduced speed penalizes a creature's Jump skill checks: each −10 ft. below 30 ft. causing the creature to suffer a −6 penalty on Jump skill checks. (This is one of the reasons the typical [lightfoot halfling](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersHtoI.html#halfling)'s +2 racial bonus on Jump skill checks is viewed with disdain, the "bonus" merely decreasing its Jump skill check penalty from −6  to −4 because of the lightfoot halfling's reduced speed.)